# javascript: fadeout but clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm building an JQM app and I'm having a few JS problems which im sure are quite easy to fix but I dont know much JS.

1) I'm placing divs on top of an image which links to over images. So when the app loads the divs are visible and then they fadeout. The problem is I want them to still be clickable and link to the other images when they are invisible.

CODE

```
 setTimeout(function () {

        $(".link").fadeIn(3000);

        $(".link").fadeOut('slow');
    }, 2000 /* Time to wait in milliseconds */);


    setTimeout();
```

Simple but I want to just make them not viewable and keep the link.

2) my second problem is I have a sound file that plays onload and two images that turn the sound file on and off. The code I made will only change the image on the home page and will not work on any other page (turning the sound on and off works but the image wont change)

CODE

```
 function playSound() {
    sound.play();
}

sound.play();
newsrc  = "soundOff.png";

function changeImage() {

    if ( newsrc == "soundOff.png" ) {
        document.getElementById("sound").src = "img/soundOff.png";
        document.getElementById("sound").alt = "Sound Off";
        newsrc  = "soundOn.png";
        sound.pause();
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("sound").src = "img/soundOn.png";
        document.getElementById("sound").alt = "Sound On";
        newsrc  = "soundOff.png";
        sound.play();
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for some of this?

Comment: The [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function might be better than `fadeOut` for you: `$('.link').animate({opacity: 0}, 2000, callback);` This way, `.link` is still present, just not visable. Also, if you're using jQuery, your `document.getElementBy...` stuff should probably be replaced with `$('#sound').attr('src')` and similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jQuery manual:

> The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

If you set the `display` property back to `inline` or `block` after the `fadeOut()` is finished, the elements will remain clickable. You can do this using the `complete` paramater of `fadeOut()`. Something like this should work:

```
$(".link").fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(".link").css({"display":"inline"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When .fadeOut is complet element `display` is none and not clickable. You should change element display property and hide it by `visibility` property. I would do that this way:

```
$(".link").fadeOut('slow', function(){
    //animation complete callback
    $(this).show().css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Comment: The opacity should already be 0 so there is no need to hide it again with `visibility`. Should work fine either way tho

Comment: yeah, that's true, but when you change `display` manually, you lose old `display` value, that was set before fading element out.